# Node Js download operation

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs and have this question regarding a scenario of file download.

I understand that the node responds to services using a single threaded event loop. When the request comes for download , the request is pushed to an async call back queue until the result(file data) is ready to be sent to the requesting user .

1. When the result is written back to the user , is this being done through the event loop cycle , or is it done differently outside the event loop ?
2. Will such kind of an operation block the server if precaution is not taken in case of a large file ? How do we handle this scenario if this can cause issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal approach to this problem in Node is [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). Streams are like UNIX pipes that can send and/or receive data. Using [`fs.createReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) will create a stream that reads from the file. Calling `pipe` on that stream can suck up all the data from that file and push it to an awaiting data sink; in your example it would be the server request. Then, without you having to worry, the reader stream will read data and raise events which the stream will dutifully pipe to the writer stream.

Here's a [stream tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/basics-node-js-streams/) that covers it in more detail.

Comment: So without 'streams' feature , the site will be blocked for the duration of download?

Comment: Phrasing it differently, Node can be made to do that operation in a blocking way. Node can be made to do it in a non-blocking way. Streams are the idiomatic way of making it asynchronous in Node. You could capture ```data``` events from a file and send them to the response yourself (which is what streams are really doing for you). You could also just read the file synchronously which _would_ block.